# Kendo editor programmatically add/remove desired sets of fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, kendo-ui

Kendo editor's font selection combobox shows all fonts as (inherited font) by default. I'd like to add my own preferred sets of fonts manually.

According to the API documentation, there seems to be no such way of doing what I need. I'm guessing maybe that I need to edit the css or manipulate the inherited fonts from the browser but I couldn't find any information on this.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using the helpers/wrappers, or JavaScript?

Comment: JSP Wrapper, but if required or recommended, I'm willing to switch it to jQuery version.

Comment: I think this should get you partway there: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/custom-tools.html - I use ASP.NET MVC, so I'm not familiar with JSP syntax, but it looks similar to the wrapper I use...

Answer (score 2):

If JavaScript version of KendoUI is fine, you might customize the list of fonts by using [`tools.items`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#configuration-tools.items).

Initializing the editor is something like:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
        // Other tools that you want to use
        {
            name : "fontName",
            items: [
                { text: "Courier", value: "Courier" },
                { text: "Times New Roman", value: "Times New Roman" },
                { text: "Trebuchet MS", value: "Trebuchet MS" }
            ]
        },
        // More tools
    ]
});
```

The only question is that you need to define all the tools, it is not incremental.

A JSFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kZegN/